# Handle client-side (or web service) built controls on PostBack

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

This is generic but lets assume I have a custom grid control and a web service which communicates with the grid so it can fill rows using XMLHttpRequest calls.  I need to add new rows. They are delivered by the web service using rendered content of a custom control (MyRow). Rows contain some controls (checkboxes, text fields, etc.). Rows and inner controls get unique, custom IDs.

Then I want to handle those newly added rows on PostBack. Is there a *best* or *approved* way of doing this? Should I read `Request.Form` - but I have to know IDs of row's inner controls? Or do I really need to serialize values (or IDs of inner controls) into hidden input(s) known and added to a page?

Really, I just want to have this handled inside MyRow but it cannot be *casted* or *deserialized* from a Request. MyRow cannot even have a brief look at form's data on PostBack. Does a page need to know how to handle internals of MyRow? Or maybe I am wrong?

I just want a custom control with support for Ajax with ability of handling values on PostBack. Even simpler, to handle client-side built controls on PostBack.

Those are plain WebForms.

Comment: If the form inputs are named couldn't you access the values on post via that name? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#control-name

Comment: @BradJanke I wish it was so simple. ASP.NET generates IDs (and names) according to hierarchy of elements, i.e. if ID of parent changes children would have different names as well. And I didn't want to guess names nor transfer them.

Comment: My solution to this is sending serialized details about rows in JSON format. Seems, this is not possible to resolve controls on PostBack in any wise way if they are not present in ViewState. The only _improvement_ to this is to prevent from sending values from original controls, thus reducing duplicated data. It can be archived by setting HTML elements as disabled just before submit.